# Problems using custom CNAME with CloudFront over SSL

Tags: ssl, amazon-cloudfront, cname

I have a problem when using a custom CNAME and SSL/HTTPS for a CloudFront distribution.  I set up a CloudFront distribution to use as a CDN on my WordPress site, using the W3TC plugin to configure things.

I imported an SSL certificate from my hosting provider to use with the CloudFront distribution.  I also configured a CNAME at my hosting for the distribution (e.g., "cdn.example.com") to use in place of the CloudFront domain name (e.g., "d1234.cloudfront.net").

After setting all this up I immediately noticed that all the images were just broken image links.  Right-clicking an image to open it in a new browser window resulted in the browser warning me that "the connection is not private" and that the website "may be impersonating cdn.example.com".  The source showed that none of the CloudFront CDN resources were being loaded.  Chrome reported "`Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID`" for several resources.

After experimenting I found that if, I stopped using the CNAME (by removing it from the W3TC plugin field) and used the CloudFront domain name (i.e., "d1234.cloudfront.net") instead, everything worked all right.   So images loaded successfully from d1234.cloudfront.net, where they wouldn't from cdn.example.com.

I have another site that is set up exactly the same except it doesn't use SSL/HTTPS: the use of a custom CNAME for the CloudFront distribution there doesn't cause any problems at all.

So the problem with CloudFront seems to appear when I try to use SSL/HTTPS *and* a custom CNAME.

The Chrome error report seems to indicate that there's a problem with the SSL certificate that I imported (what, I don't know - I'm not at all clued-up with SSL certificates).  If that's the cause of the problem, should I get a certificate from AWS to enable the use of a custom CNAME?  If so, what should I stipulate for the certificate? And I'm not sure how that works having two certificates - one for my domain and another for CloudFront?

Comment: Your SSL cert needs to have a SAN (subject alt. name) that includes both your `cdn.example.com` and `d1234.cloudfront.net` names.

Comment: So if my site domain is `www.example.com`, and I will be using `cdn.example.com` as my CloudFront CNAME, then I should request a certificate from AWS that includes the domains `www.example.com`, `*.example.com` and `d1234.cloudfront.net` ?

Comment: Well, if you use `*.example.com` then you don't need `www.example.com` but otherwise, pretty much.

Comment: Thanks - but do I delete my existing certificate from my hosting provider? (Said I was a bit clueless about certificates!)

Comment: The request for a certificate that covers `d1234.cloudfront.net` failed because you aren't allowed any ending with `cloudfront.net`

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you may have missed adding your CNAME to the Cloudfront distribution, i.e. under 'Alternate Domains Names':-
[image: Adding your CNAME to Cloudfront]

(I know this is an old question but as it stands unresolved and I just hit the same issue, I think this might help others)

Comment: Not sure what you mean - select the distribution, click edit, and it's the 3rd option on the page, i.e. "Alternate domain name (CNAME) - optional". Or if creating a new distribution it's there under the Settings section.

Answer (score 1):

Below are the issues.

1. Certificate does not match issuers name
2. Google Chrome browser error
3. Address error due Certificate Mismatch

Please check SSL generated for domain is valid and uploaded same to cloudfront.